# href задать значение

Tags: java, spring-boot, href

Всем доброго дня.Вопрос по JAVA Spring Boot Либо неправильно ищу, либо не знаю что ищу. Сразу пардон если вопрос был, мне не попался. Есть такая ссылка, это день месяца

```
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/options">2</a></li>
```

Можно ли ей задать значение в виде "2019-11-02" и передать его в репозиторий (соответственно как это сделать или ресурс с примером), где происходит поиск по базе. Смысл задачи, при нажатии на день месяца вылезают записи сделанные на этот день.

```
@Query(value = "select id, car, client, create_date, info, manager, sistem, work, work_date " +
    "from jobform where work_date like '2019-11-02'", nativeQuery = true)
```

List getAllByDate();
Вставить это значение надо в то место, где указана дата. Или может есть другие варианты.

Comment: `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/options/2"`

Comment: Допустим есть рест: `@RequestMapping("/options/{yourValue}")`. Получить значение `yourValue` можно так: `public void yourMethod(@PathVariable int yourValue) {...}`

Comment: более подробно можно почитать [тут](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates)